# Failed to disable decryption server side in spring cloud config server

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud-config

According to the spring cloud config documentation, if we want to disable server side decryption and handle it by the client, we can put in server’s application.yml the following property :

```
spring:
 cloud:
  config:
   server:
    encrypt.enabled: false
```

In server side, a define an env variable `ENCRYPT_KEY` then a call a `curl` to get encrypted password, I update the configuration file then I commit it

```
export ENCRYPTED=`curl config-server/encrypt -d ms-password-prod`
echo "spring.data.mongodb.paswword='{cipher}$ENCRYPTED'" >> establishment-services-prod.yml
```

Now, when I call

```
curl -v config-server:9090/establishment-services/prod
```

I expect to see encrypted password but I get the password decrypted.

I used `spring-boot 1.5.8` and `spring-cloud Dalston.SR4`.

You can find all the code in my [Github](https://github.com/AndolsiZied/microservices-samples/tree/master/ms-technical-platform) account.

Comment: Can you try and move `spring.cloud.config.server.encrypt.enabled` to `bootstrap.yml` in your config server setup?

Comment: Moving `spring.cloud.config.server.encrypt.enabled` to `bootstrap.ymll`  solves the problem.
I think it is necessary to think of this alternative as a solution.
Please, put your comment as an answer to accept it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Moving the `spring.cloud.config.server.encrypt.enabled` key to the `bootstrap` configuration file of your config server should fix the issue.

Looking at the project documentation, I'm not sure if this is a workaround or the intended behavior, as it seems that only the `encrypt.*` keys belong in the bootstrap configuration.

This could be a bug or a documentation enhancement that you could report on [the issue tracker spring-cloud-config](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-config/issues).

Comment: probably it didnt that time but now docs say that, see 2.8 https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/single/spring-cloud-config.html#_encryption_and_decryption