# spring-cloud-config-server alway decrypt the encrypted message?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, encryption, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config

I am running a spring cloud config server.I follow the user guide,and successfully start it up,it can load the configuration from github [config-repo/licensingservice/licensingservice.yml](https://github.com/carnellj/config-repo/blob/master/licensingservice/licensingservice.yml)
 .I can use the /decrypt and /encript endpoints ,but when I run `http://localhost:8888/licensingservice/default`
it always decrypts the sensitive message
`spring.datasource.password: "{cipher}4788dfe1ccbe6485934aec2ffeddb06163ea3d616df5fd75be96aadd4df1da91"` into
`"spring.datasource.password": "p0stgr@s"`
I have put **spring.cloud.config.server.encrypt.enabled=false** in bootstrap.yml, and can see it by the

```
localhost:8888/actuator/env
```

[image: check from actuator]

the configuration on the github:

```
    example.property: "I AM IN THE DEFAULT"
spring.jpa.database: "POSTGRESQL"
spring.datasource.platform:  "postgres"
spring.jpa.show-sql: "true"
spring.database.driverClassName: "org.postgresql.Driver"
spring.datasource.url: "jdbc:postgresql://database:5432/eagle_eye_local"
spring.datasource.username: "postgres"
spring.datasource.password: "{cipher}4788dfe1ccbe6485934aec2ffeddb06163ea3d616df5fd75be96aadd4df1da91"
spring.datasource.testWhileIdle: "true"
spring.datasource.validationQuery: "SELECT 1"
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect: "org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect"
redis.server: "redis"
redis.port: "6379"
signing.key: "345345fsdfsf5345"
```

configuration get from postman:

```
{
    "name": "licensingservice",
    "profiles": [
        "default"
    ],
    "label": null,
    "version": "56d63a8c0c3dcb0c5c93db1f00cf71856371db8b",
    "state": null,
    "propertySources": [
        {
            "name": "https://github.com/carnellj/config-repo//licensingservice/licensingservice.yml",
            "source": {
                "example.property": "I AM IN THE DEFAULT",
                "spring.jpa.database": "POSTGRESQL",
                "spring.datasource.platform": "postgres",
                "spring.jpa.show-sql": "true",
                "spring.database.driverClassName": "org.postgresql.Driver",
                "spring.datasource.url": "jdbc:postgresql://database:5432/eagle_eye_local",
                "spring.datasource.username": "postgres",
                "spring.datasource.testWhileIdle": "true",
                "spring.datasource.validationQuery": "SELECT 1",
                "spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect": "org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect",
                "redis.server": "redis",
                "redis.port": "6379",
                "signing.key": "345345fsdfsf5345",
                "spring.datasource.password": "p0stgr@s"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

my build script:

```
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile

plugins {
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "2.3.1.RELEASE"
    id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.0.9.RELEASE"
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.3.72"
    kotlin("plugin.spring") version "1.3.72"
}

group = "com.matches"
version = "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"
java.sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

extra["springCloudVersion"] = "Hoxton.SR6"

dependencies {
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8")
    implementation("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-config-server")
    implementation("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-config")
    implementation("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-eureka")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator")
    testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test") {
        exclude(group = "org.junit.vintage", module = "junit-vintage-engine")
    }
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:${property("springCloudVersion")}")
    }
}

tasks.withType<Test> {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

tasks.withType<KotlinCompile> {
    kotlinOptions {
        freeCompilerArgs = listOf("-Xjsr305=strict")
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
}
```

ConfigserverApplication：

```
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication
import org.springframework.boot.runApplication
import org.springframework.cloud.config.server.EnableConfigServer

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableConfigServer
class ConfigserverApplication

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    runApplication<ConfigserverApplication>(*args)
}
```

I can not find out why it alway decrypts the password?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**spring-cloud-config-server always decrypt the encrypted message?** *NO*

**ConfigClient** can also decrypt if we set `encrypt` to `false` like this in **ConfigServer**.

```
spring:
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        encrypt:
          enabled: false
        git:
          uri: linkToYourURI
```

And in the **ConfigClient** use the key for decryption like this.
Remember to put this in `bootstrap.yml` as for `application.yml` it will be too late, see this for [further clarification](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47476900/6332074).

```
encrypt:
  key: PutYourKeyHere
```

Comment: Great.Makes me realize the execution order of bootstrap.yml and application.yml.Thanks

Comment: Did you get your answer?

Comment: Yes,have fixed it.Thanks